Script runs twice when I `import` a variable
I would appreciate a quick help. I’m working on this project and there is a part where I have to use the scene variable elsewhere so I exported it but every time I import it, the main.js where the scene was intantiated, runs again
so I always end up having 2 canvas since my scene initialization ran twice
./main.js 
export const scene = new THREE.Scene()

./renderModel.js
import { scene } from '../main'

export function renderModels() {
    scene.add(Primary.mesh)
}

I tried using global variable, which works but I would like to find out what’s causing this error.

Log some debug messages to trace where this bug is occurring at. Although if you are importing this file; main.js, in other places, that is the culprit since it will be instantiated each time and returned to the importing file.

"every time I import it, the main.js where the scene was intantiated, runs again" - no it doesn't. A module is evaluated only once.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]

Better design is for modules to just define classes and functions, not have direct side effects. Then the script that imports it can call the functions to instantiate things as needed.

@Barmar If the module were to run twice, it would still define two separate classes, which would cause problems that are really hard to debug. While I agree in general, I don't think this will solve the problem here.
